# git describe fails with "fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything."

Tags: git

I'm using git 1.7.1 on Ubuntu 10.10 amd64, and I'm trying to extract the hash of my repository HEAD to use it in an automated version information that I compile into my project.

In the past, this always worked by using

```
git describe --tags
```

however, git is now throwing

```
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
```

at me. Does anyone have a clue what that means?

Google showed only few hits and no solution.

Comment: Do you actually want only the hash, or is the information put together by git describe useful to you? The most recent tag, and the number of intermediate commits, are much more human-readable than an SHA1. @nes: You might want to undelete your answer, since it could be exactly what the OP needs - it's hard to tell.

Comment: Personal reminder: check that the remote *actually has tags* using for instance `git ls-remote --tags`. In my case the repo has been recently migrated to a new server and the tags had not been transfered yet !

Comment: Thanks @GabrielDevillers for the obvious hint. I´ve created tags within Visual Studio and did not know, that with a "normal" push the tags are not included. Here´s a link how to push tags from within VS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71733250/13624968

Answer (score 105):

I have had this problem in a CI build environment where the CI tool was performing a shallow clone of the repository. This was frustrating, because in my development environment, the command

```
git describe --tags
```

would give me output like

```
2.2.12-7-g8ec9d6c9
```

whereas in the build environment I would get the "fatal no names found" error. If I tried using the --always tag

```
git describe --tags --always
```

then I would simply get the hash of the latest commit, but not the most recent tag prior to that commit

```
8ec9d6c9
```

Performing a `git pull` in the build environment wouldn't help, because once the repo has been cloned shallowly, future pulls will not update the tags.

The solution was to ensure that the initial clone of the repo in the build environment was not a shallow clone (i.e. the `git clone` command was not used with `--depth`, `--shallow-since` or `--shallow-exclude` parameters).

Comment: I had the exact same issue, thanks for your insight!

Comment: Adding `git fetch --depth=500` worked for me with Travis-CI.

Comment: that's the answer I wanted as well!

Comment: Yep - adding this to `.travis.yml` fixed it for me:
`git:
  depth: false`

Comment: You can also simply do `git fetch --tags` in the shallow clone, to fetch the missing tags

Comment: @LukeH: My understanding is that a shallow copy can not be represented by a tag. So it wouldn't help for that particular problem. --unshallow is needed

Comment: For github action adding `fetch-depth: 0` to checkout action will going to fetch all the tags and branches.

Answer (score 93):

If you want the id of your `HEAD` then you don't need `describe`, you should just use `rev-parse`.

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

If you want an abbreviated hash you can use `--short`.

```
git rev-parse --short HEAD
```

If you want a "describe" to fall back to an abbreviated hash if it can't find any suitable tags, you can use `--always`.

```
git describe --always
```

Comment: Yeah, that returns the hash, but what I acutally want is the abbreviated hash that is normally returned by git-describe which has like 8 characters or so

Comment: @Philipp: `git describe` normally returns a tag object based string consisting of the tag name, a number of commits and and a suffix based on the hash. It doesn't normally return an abbreviated hash so I'm not quite sure what your asking for.

Comment: On my macOS git 2.39.1 `git describe --tags` returns something like `0.16.0-22-g4ce71cd` which has the format `[closest-tag]-[num_commits-between_tag_and_head]-[sha1_short]`. That's likely to be what most recent readers want.

Answer (score 48):

This happens if you don't have any tags in your repository. If the repository *does* have tags, then you're in a shallow clone (this is the default in CI systems like TravisCI or GitHub Actions).

To fetch the history (including tags) from within a shallow clone, run

```
git fetch --prune --unshallow
```

For example, in the case of GitHub actions:

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
- run: git fetch --prune --unshallow
```

Afterwards, `git describe` should work again.

Comment: For GitHub Actions, `--tags` was needed in my case - so `git fetch --prune --unshallow --tags`. See [this issue](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/206)

Comment: While this will work and solves the issue for shallow repos on Github Workflows, isn't --unshallowing going to actually fetch the whole history of the repository ? A big repo with a lot of history will cause problems by adding a bottleneck to the CI pipeline.

Comment: Yes, this will fetch the whole history. Since a tag is a pointer to a revision, that revision must be present for the tag to function properly.

Answer (score 42):

It sounds like you're expecting `git-describe` to include the most recent tag and number of commits since that tag. However, the `fatal: No names found` message means you *don't have any tags* in your repository. You need to have at least one tag in the commit history in order for `git describe` to tell you the latest tag.

Just guessing, but perhaps you tagged a commit somewhere else, but never pushed the tag upstream (maybe you pushed the commit upstream, tagged it later, and didn't repush?). Now a new clone of your upstream is giving you this error (since it doesn't have any tag). If that's the case, you could try `git push --tags` from the repository that has the tag you want (where `git describe` is doing what you expect). Then do `git pull` on the repository that doesn't have the tag.

Answer (score 18):

If you're using GitHub Actions and the [actions/checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout), you should set the `fetch-depth` to `0`:

```yaml
# ...
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
```

Comment: "Set fetch-depth: 0 to fetch all history for all branches and tags". How highly inefficient (as pointed in the other comments)

Comment: I am on a repo with 1500+ commits, and actually the difference between `fetch-depth`: 0 vs 50 is negligible (~1-3 sec) on GH Action workflows. I'd rather be a bit more inefficient than miss getting tag.

Answer (score 11):

I had the similar issue while working on a CI job, the issue was git clone or checkout scm used did not fetch tags while cloning the repo.

Fetching without tags
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.**********

You can enable fetch tags by selecting "Advanced clone behaviours" and then clicking on fetch tags ..

[image: Screenshot_enabling_git_fetch]

Answer (score 5):

This command helped me:
`git fetch -t`

It fetch the latest tags from the git repository, and is therefore enable to describe the tags.

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187/is-try-this-bad-practice), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: Terse as it may be, this is the only answer which mentions `fetch`.

Comment: OP's problem was that his local repository did not have any tags. If the remote has, but the local not, you can fetch the tags using git fetch -t or git fetch --tags

Comment: This command really solved my problem too and none of the other responses.

Comment: It helped me too!

Answer (score 4):

**If you're using Github Actions and checkout@v3**

You'll run into this issue because by default the action fetches only the last commit, and as mentioned by the other posts, if this commit is not tagged, then `git describe --tags` will crash (it crashes when it cannot find a tag)

There is a [open PR somewhat ignored by the Github staff](https://github.com/actions/checkout/pull/579) meant to fix this.

In the meantime, you have several options

- fetch all commits ([see answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71721059/2832282))
- hacking the aforementioned answer and taking inspiration from other answers/comments : fetch X commits (hoping you don't have more than X untagged commits between your head and the last tagged commit) with something like (X = 50)

```
# ...
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 50
```

Comment: The PR is merged, and `fetch-tags` is available in actions/checkout@v>=3.6.0. But it may not be a solution. My experience is the same as https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/701#issuecomment-1935456395

Answer (score 2):

If you came here due to this error message in Travis CI, you can use the following setting to avoid shallow clones:

```
git:
  depth: false
```

I tested `git fetch --tags` but that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

This issue happens after cloning a forked branch, and disappears after rebasing from the upstream.

Before rebasing:

```
#  git describe --tags
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
```

After rebasing:

```
# git describe --tags
v0.1.xxxx
```

The command to rebase:

```
git remote add upstream xxxxx
git checkout main
git remote prune origin
git fetch -p upstream 
git rebase upstream/main
```

Answer (score 1):

Gitlab 14.7 changed the default `git depth` from 50 to 20 which caused our CI pipelines to fail with this error.  Where this is an issue you might notice something like the following in the CI logs:

`INFO:git.cmd:git describe --tags  -> 128; stdout: '<OUTPUT_STREAM>'; stderr: 'fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.'`

This can be solved by:

- including [`GIT_DEPTH`](https://gitlab.mdcatapult.io/help/ci/large_repositories/index.md#shallow-cloning)
  in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file

  or
- changing the 'Git shallow clone' value in the Gitlab UI via Settings -> CI/CD -> General Pipelines. Change to 0 to disable shallow cloning.
  Refer to the gitlab [docs](https://gitlab.mdcatapult.io/help/ci/pipelines/settings#limit-the-number-of-changes-fetched-during-clone) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me with

```
- name: Checkout repo
    uses: actions/checkout@v4
    with:
      fetch-depth: 0
      submodules: recursive
```