# Bamboo Gradle build fails with "fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything"

Tags: git, gradle, bamboo

I've inherited a Bamboo build that runs deploys on a remote agent. When I run it, the build in Bamboo is marked as "successful," but the `deploy` task is eventually skipped due to a fatal exception - here's a snippet of the logs:

```
build   17-Jan-2019 10:25:33    Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
build   17-Jan-2019 10:25:39    :cleanPackage UP-TO-DATE
build   17-Jan-2019 10:25:39    :copyFiles
build   17-Jan-2019 10:25:39    diffTarget: SIT
error   17-Jan-2019 10:25:39    fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
build   17-Jan-2019 10:25:39    build.gradle
build   17-Jan-2019 10:25:39    :deploy SKIPPED
build   17-Jan-2019 10:25:39    
build   17-Jan-2019 10:25:39    BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

The Bamboo build is setup to check out a repository, then run a task called `deploy`:

[image]

I'm thinking that the issue may be happening when checking out the repository (I am completely new to Gradle) - I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916492/git-describe-fails-with-fatal-no-names-found-cannot-describe-anything) where the exact same exception was thrown where the OP was explicitly running git describe on the command line. So, I'm guessing that it's a git exception and possibly something is configured incorrectly with the git commands?

One other thing to note is that in the build.gradle file, I have Bitbucket creds, but I intentionally switched bewteen invalid credentials and working credentials, and the output was the same - so I'm thinking it's not something specific to this repository itself.

Does anyone have any suggestions/where I should look to troubleshoot? Anything is helpful, even if it's validating that this is likely a Git config issue, and not something else. Let me know if there's any other information I should include - like I said, I'm a total novice with this :)

Comment: Hey Brian - is there evidence (past builds) that this ever worked?  The way Bamboo checks out git repositories is not straight foward.  It looks like the gradle build is attempting to use git describe - perhaps as the task name suggests to determine the differences between what is deployed and what is to be deployed to minimize what is copied to the deploy environment.  Perhaps the current directory is not a git repo when the command runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone that stumbles across this, the issue was exactly the same in the linked question, and had nothing to do with Bamboo itself - the Gradle script was making a `git describe --tags` call, but the repository had no tags defined.

(I failed to include the necessary Gradle snippet in the original question, apologies to any poor souls that lost sleep over this):

```
result = exec{
    commandLine "git", "describe", "--tags", "--match", "$diffTarget-*", "--abbrev=0"
    standardOutput = stdout
    ignoreExitValue = true
}
```