# Visual Studio 2022 Git Push Tags

Tags: git, visual-studio-2022

Does anybody know how to push tags in Visual Studio 2022. Since I switched to multi-repo mode, I can't find it anywhere.
Workaround is to push the tags via command line.

Comment: Please upvote! => https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Why-is-there-no-tag-management-content-i/1508117?space=8&q=git+tag+management

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I raised the issue at Microsoft and this is not yet available when using the multi-repo preview. Will probably be added at a later stage.

Comment: Microsoft please fix this!  Add Tag Management Support Please!!!

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Why-is-there-no-tag-management-content-i/1508117?space=8&q=git+tag+management

Answer (score 35):

The truth is that tags are a bit hidden. You should go to **team explorer ->  Git Repository -> under your branch -> right click -> New tag**.

[image]

Then you will have to push these tags under **Git changes -> three dots -> push all tags to origin.**

[image]

*Tags pushed*

[image]

Tag is attached to a particular commit. You can then find your tags on github along with the commit that they are connected.

[image]

Comment: Indeed, in Visual Studio 2019 that was the way to go. But I can't find it back in Visual studio 2022. Note, I'm using the multi-repo option at the moment.

Comment: @TimD'haeyer the above explanation is performed on VS 2022, but I am not sure about the multi-repo option.