github workflow action not matching cli when matching tags to commits
My build uses the most recent git tag to deduce version at runtime
This is working on my local environment
When I have a github workflow (triggered on a tag) do the build, it gets it wrong. A little debug shows that it is GIT that is getting it wrong, but I don't see what is messing up?
git log shows my commit, describe shows the previous tag + many commits, but show-ref --tags shows that the tag hash matches the commit hash.
What is happening here? This even has an issue when I wait for minutes and re-run the jobs.
Output from within the workflow job:
  git describe
  git log -1
  git show-ref --tags
  python setup.py bdist_wheel
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
v0.0.27-13-g9e62705
commit 9e6270590ad7824870a77b809de415c577a42821
Date:   Mon Aug 5 15:52:04 2024 -0700
    Stable and working version from tags.
bfe0fc0472e23b657cdc600721e8042be32d1c05 refs/tags/v0.0.27
9e6270590ad7824870a77b809de415c577a42821 refs/tags/v0.0.28

Showing that:

Git knows there are tags and commits v0.0.27-13-g9e62705
The githash from log -1 is the same as the tag from show-ref pointing to my desired tag
describe is using the same commit as the log and the tag

This workflow is already using:
    uses: actions/checkout@v4
    with:
      fetch-depth: 0
      fetch-tags: true

as shown by git describe knowing about the previous tag and the number of commits past.

By default, GitHub action workflows do a shallow commit, so the history of commits and tags isn't available. For git describe to work as you expect, you need to fetch at least until the most recent tag. Adding fetch-depth: 0 to the checkout step should fix this for you.

There's also fetch-tags: true but I don't know if it would work for you.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71721059/3216427 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/76181083/3216427 answering a question related to yours.

Uodated: already using fetch-depth: 0 and fetch-tags.
git describe found v0.0.27-13-g9e62705 which known about the other tags, and the 13 commits between them. and the githash of the tag that it knows is v0.0.28

All right, that is very odd, and I admit, your question had all that in the first place, sorry for not noticing. This is definitely an unexpected behaviour.

For some reason I don't understand, you need to provide the --tags option to git describe.
In a test workflow I just created, I got these results on a tag push:
Run git describe
  git describe
  git describe --tags
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
v0.0.2-1-gb5c0da7
v0.0.3

My git describe output  (v0.0.2-1-gb5c0da7) is consistent with yours, displaying the same unexpected result.
My git describe --tags output is correct: v0.0.3 since the workflow I'm looking at was on the push of that tag.
Relevant issue on GitHub actions: https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/272

PS: Thanks for asking the question! This may help me solve a problem in one of our workflows.
