# How can I get the Git build number and embed it in a file?

Tags: git, version, embed

I want to introduce a versioning constant grabbed from the version in Git. I know how to do this -- in  a very hackish way in svn --

any ideas on how to do this with Git?

Comment: Do you want this embedded in a file like `$Id$`? That doesn't really work. If you just want to describe a build in whole though, `git describe`

Comment: Yeah I do want to do something similar to that, or even maybe write a file version.log that I could parse

Comment: Similar to $ID$ -- sorry. I need to reuse that build number in my php code

Comment: **Git** is not an acronym. It's just "Git", not "GIT".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For me, git describe didn't initially give the hashtag. The following did, however:

```
git describe --all --long
```

This results in something of the by kubi described format. Supposing you would only want the last part (hashtag) something like the following would do (saving to version.txt file):

```
git describe --all --long | tr "-" " " | awk '{ print $3 }' > version.txt
```

**EDIT**: As a friend pointed out to me this can actually be done using just `cut` instead, if you so desire:

```
git describe --all --long | cut -d "-" -f 3 > version.txt
```

Comment: this actually was closer to what I wanted. Now I just need to find a way to embed it in a file. I want to reference the build id in code

Comment: This seems to be a different question, but it is most definitely possible. In PHP: `$git_version = file_get_contents("version.txt");` - now `$git_version` contains the hash :)

Answer (score 7):

Here's what I do:

As part of my build process I run the following script (paraphrased, since I'm not at Xcode right now)

```
git describe --all > version.txt
```

Inside my application I read the version number out of this file and display it to the user (when necessary). Make sure you add *version.txt* to your *.gitignore*. The benefit of doing it this way is that if you tag your releases `git describe` will just output the tag, otherwise it'll output the commit hash.

Comment: to me this gives me the branch name but not the version #

Comment: It will give you <last reachable tag>-<commits since tag>-<8 digit hash>

Comment: @kubi No. Its 7 digit hash with prefix `g`.

Comment: For me it's git describe  (without --all) (I am using 1.9.5.msysgit.0)

Answer (score 4):

Note: it is interesting to see how Git itself computes its own build number.
That just evolved in Git 2.12 (Q1 2017)

See [commit a765974](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a7659747c2eeb0c601ced321446da92149310cd0) (04 Dec 2016) by [Ramsay Jones (``)](https://github.com/).
Helped-by: [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0a45050](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0a45050a1456ed18a0b886f60b1b217b4db165ae), 19 Dec 2016)</sup>

```
GIT-VERSION-GEN 

VN=$(git describe --match "v[0-9]*" HEAD 2>/dev/null) 
# instead of
VN=$(git describe --match "v[0-9]*" --abbrev=7 HEAD 2>/dev/null)
```

> ### `GIT-VERSION-GEN`: do not force abbreviation length used by '`describe`'
>
> The default version name for a Git binary is computed by running "`git describe`" on the commit the binary is made out of, basing on a tag whose name matches "`v[0-9]*`", e.g. `v2.11.0-rc2-2-g7f1dc9`.
>
> In the very early days, with [9b88fce ("`Makefile`: use `git-describe`
>   to mark the git version.", 2005-12-27)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9b88fcef7dd6327cc3aba3927e56fef6f6c4d628), we used "`--abbrev=4`" to get
>   absolute minimum number of abbreviated commit object name.
>   This was later changed to match the default minimum of 7 with [bf50515
>   ("Git 1.7.10.1", 2012-05-01)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bf505158d0292eed441fff1bc9157da19645ee91).
>
> **These days, the "default minimum" scales automatically depending on
>   the size of the repository**, and there is no point in specifying a
>   particular abbreviation length; all we wanted since Git 1.7.10.1
>   days was to get "something reasonable we would use by default".

(That was introduced in Git 2.11: see the last part of "[How much of a git sha is *generally* considered necessary to uniquely identify a change in a given codebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21015031/6309)")

> Just drop "`--abbrev=<number>`" from the invocation of "`git describe`"
>   and let the command pick what it thinks is appropriate, taking the
>   end user's configuration and the repository contents into account.

Answer (score 3):

To get Git revision in php, I use something like this (change your paths to .Git catalog)

```
public static function getGitRevision()
     {
         $rev = trim(file_get_contents(NT_Path::ROOT . "/.git/HEAD"));

         if (substr($rev, 0, 4) == 'ref:') {
             $ref =  end(explode('/', $rev));
             $rev = trim(file_get_contents(NT_Path::ROOT . "/.git/refs/heads/{$ref}"));
         }

         return $rev;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting it in a text file then getting the contents of it each time, this appears to work quite well:

```
sed -i.bak "s/$version = '.*';/$version = '`git rev-parse --short HEAD | tr -d '\n'`';/g" version.php
```

where version.php looks like this:

```
<?php
$version = 'some version string';
```

and then just include the file in your script as you would a settings file.

You could also use `git describe --all --long` as your version string if you wanted to, I preferred the git-hash from `git-ref-parse --short HEAD` for my purposes.

Or as a constant which may be better:

```
sed -i.bak "s/define('VERSION','.*');/define('VERSION','`git describe --all --long | cut -d "-" -f 3`');/g" version.php
```

and version.php:

```
<?php
define('VERSION','some version string');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have done it.  Note:  Python code to get revision came from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14989858/get-the-current-git-hash-in-a-python-script) post.

BuildInfo.hpp

```
#ifndef BUILDINFO_HPP_
#define BUILDINFO_HPP_

struct BuildInfo
{
    static const char Name[];
    static const char GitRevision[];
};

#endif
```

(Auto Generated) BuildInfo.cpp

```
#include "BuildInfo.hpp"

const char BuildInfo::Name[] = "MyAppNAme";
const char BuildInfo::GitRevision[] = "5e854351b342acff6a3481d9106076df379c449a";
```

GenerateBuildInfo.py.  Python script to generate BuildInfo.cpp.  Note that this could be easily adapted to get short or long revision numbers or other repository info.  It could also be converted to generate C code rather than cpp so is compatible with both.

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess

#args: [0]: this script path [1]: Output file name [2]: Application name string

# Return the git revision as a string
def git_version():
    def _minimal_ext_cmd(cmd):
        # construct minimal environment
        env = {}
        for k in ['SYSTEMROOT', 'PATH']:
            v = os.environ.get(k)
            if v is not None:
                env[k] = v
        # LANGUAGE is used on win32
        env['LANGUAGE'] = 'C'
        env['LANG'] = 'C'
        env['LC_ALL'] = 'C'
        out = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, env=env).communicate()[0]
        return out

    try:
        out = _minimal_ext_cmd(['git', 'rev-parse', 'HEAD'])
        GIT_REVISION = out.strip().decode('ascii')
    except OSError:
        GIT_REVISION = "Unknown"

    return GIT_REVISION

if len(sys.argv) < 2 :
    exit("No output file name argument provided")
elif len(sys.argv) >= 3 :
    name = sys.argv[2]
else :
    name = ""

revision = git_version()
if (revision == "Unknown") :
    exit("Cant get git revision")

with open(sys.argv[1], "w") as f :
    f.write('#include "BuildInfo.hpp"\r\n\r\n')
    f.write('const char BuildInfo::Name[] = "' + name + '";\r\n')
    f.write('const char BuildInfo::GitRevision[] = "' + revision + '";\r\n')
    f.close()
```

To use the build info

```
#include "BuildInfo.hpp"
...
PrintRevision(BuildInfo::GitRevision);
```

To generate BuildInfo.cpp, in a post build step I call (from eclipse IDE in this case)

```
python ${ProjDirPath}/build/GenerateBuildInfo.py ${ProjDirPath}/src/BuildInfo.cpp ${ProjName}
```