# how to get last commit id of the git repo in python

Tags: python, git

I would like to know the exact git commit id in a repository. 
May be like latest commit(most recent) and 2nd most recent commit.

I have tried git commands like below, but I need the same in python script.

> **$ git rev-parse @** most recent Output: 669ec6662bedc7a9962bef83612a33522a8e4fb8
>
> **$ git rev-parse @~** 2nd most recent Output: 97a90650792efdbef3f6abb92bd6108c11889cc6

Answer (score 6):

You can do that using `subprocess` module. This code will return a list containing the last two commits, where the first item in the list is the latest.

```
import subprocess

def get_git_revisions_hash():
    hashes = []
    hashes.append(subprocess.check_output(['git', 'rev-parse', 'HEAD']))
    hashes.append(subprocess.check_output(['git', 'rev-parse', 'HEAD^']))
    return hashes
```

The same can also be achieved with list comprehension. This solution is more extendable, because you don't need to add additional subprocess calls:

```
commits = ['HEAD', 'HEAD^']
def get_git_revisions_hash2():
    return [subprocess.check_output(['git', 'rev-parse', '{}'.format(x)])
            for x in commits]
```

There is also [GitPython](http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) module, which gives you an interface to git. You can read the docs, it gives more builtin tools for git.

Comment: to get it as a clean string one can augment like follows: `subprocess.check_output(['git', 'rev-parse', 'HEAD']).strip().decode('ascii')` as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14989858/get-the-current-git-hash-in-a-python-script#comment93332441_21901260 and elsewhere