# how to interpret git describe output

Tags: git

I was playing with git describe:

```
git branch
  branch1
* master

git tag tag1 HEAD~2

git tag tag2 HEAD

git describe --all HEAD~1
tags/tag1-1-gb772e8b

git rev-parse tag1
1ae346a3b91f5dbe4110ae143ce86825d79b82f3
```

What does it mean by "1-gb772e8b" in "tag1-1-gb772e8b" ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
tag1-1-gb772e8b
^    ^  ^ 
|    |  |
|    |  git hash of the commit  
|    |
|   number of commits after the tag 
|
|
Most recent tag
```

This is all in reference to the commit you are giving to git describe.
In your case it is HEAD~1, so

- HEAD~1 has commit hash b772e8b
- HEAD~1 is 1 commit after the most recent tag
- the most recent tag older than HEAD~1 is tag1

See the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe) for more in-depth information, the output depends on
whether there are any tags, and what state the repository is in and arguments you provide to `git describe`

There's also a `g` in the hash,`gb772e8b`. The [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe) describe it as

> The "g" prefix stands for "git" and is used to allow describing the
>   version of a software depending on the SCM the software is managed
>   with.