# get info describing current checkout in git

Tags: git

I have a codebase which has been migrated from mercurial to git recently, yet its version detection has not been adopted yet.

While I know how to obtain each piece of information by a separate git command (`git rev-parse HEAD`, `git status`, `git log`) scraping their outputs. I wonder whether I can be more brief and get things as a nicely tab or space-separated list for easy digestion within python. I need

- the commit's hash
- whether it's an unmodified checkout
- any tag associated with it (if any)
- the time and date the commit was made

Basically I'm trying to created an an extended version of [Get the current git hash in a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14989858/get-the-current-git-hash-in-a-python-script) and need pointers to use more appropriated git commands than so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just `echo` those commands together, something like:

```
 echo \
     $(git log -1 --pretty='%h "%cd"') \
     \"$(git tag --points-at HEAD)\" \
     $(git ls-files -m | wc -l)
```

Comment: Thanks. Something similar I ended up doing. Actually running a separate command for each. Easier and especially saver with respect to different environments and catching things like no tags etc. https://github.com/OpenTTD/nml/pull/1