# Logging the git_sha as a parameter on Mlflow using Kedro hooks

Tags: python, mlflow, kedro, mlops

I would like to log the git_sha parameter on Mlflow as shown in the [documentation](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/07_extend_kedro/02_hooks.html?highlight=run_params#add-metrics-tracking-to-your-model). What appears to me here, is that simply running the following portion of code should be enough to get git_sha logged in the Mlflow UI. Am I right ?

```
@hook_impl
    def before_pipeline_run(self, run_params: Dict[str, Any]) -> None:
        """Hook implementation to start an MLflow run
        with the same run_id as the Kedro pipeline run.
        """
        mlflow.start_run(run_name=run_params["run_id"])
        mlflow.log_params(run_params)
```

But this does not work as I get all but the git_sha parameter. And when I look at the [hooks specs](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/kedro/framework/hooks/specs.html?highlight=run_params#), it seems that this param is not part of run_params (anymore?)

Is there a way I could get the git sha (maybe from the context journal ?) and add it to the logged parameters ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst it's heavily encouraged to use git with Kedro it's not required and as such no part of Kedro (except [kedro-starters](https://github.com/quantumblacklabs/kedro-starters) if we're being pedantic) is 'aware' of git.

In your `before_pipeline_hook` there it is pretty easy for you to retrieve the info [via the techniques documented here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14989858/get-the-current-git-hash-in-a-python-script). It seems trivial for the whole codebase, a bit more involved if you want to say provide pipeline specific hashes.