# How can I get the commit where the head is pointing to?

Tags: python, git, gitlab, gitlab-api

My Git HEAD is pointing to a commit that is not the last one committed so I would like to get that commit. Is it possible through the GitLab API? If so how can I do it from Python or a curl command?

In case GitLab does not provide any mechanism to do so, how can I do it using a Git command from Python?

Comment: are you looking for `git rev-parse HEAD` ?

Comment: @LeGEC yep, i found it here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21901260/1624552

Comment: or `git ls-remote origin HEAD` ?

Comment: Or may be [Get a single commit API call](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#get-a-single-commit) with `:sha` being `HEAD`.

Comment: @LeGEC your solution works. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21901260/1624552