# Do I have to update project version when only README has changed on GitHub?

Tags: github, version, versioning, bower, semantic-versioning

I'm editing one of my open-source projects on GitHub and I want to replace link (pointing to a demo) in `README.md`.

Do I have to update library version every time I introduce some minor changes to the README file or documentation (without any actual code changes)?

#### What is the community accepted practice?

If it's important, I'm using **Bower** to distribute my package and **SemVer** as a versioning system.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The *README* file is part of your codebase. It should describe the current (= in current commit) state of the code. A developer might read it outside GitHub's environment, e.g. from the `node_modules` directory on their hard drive, expecting it is up to date.

Therefore I would **recommend to release a new version** when the *README* changes.

It will usually result in just a patch number increase. But remember that when marking something as *deprecated* one must release a new minor version (paragraph 7 in [SemVer v2.0.0](http://semver.org/spec/v2.0.0.html)).

If you plan to do really a lot of changes there are two ways to avoid releasing too often:

- Make changes in a branch. Merge to `master` here and there, release a new patch version.
- Move the documentation (or a part of it) somewhere else. GitHub Wiki or a simple webpage, e.g. using GitHub Pages, could come in handy.

Comment: Thanks, I think it's the best possible course of action.

Answer (score 3):

You could include, as library version, the content of of `git describe --all --long`, as described in [How can I get the Git build number and embed it in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8579274/6309) (using [`git describe`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe)).

That way, you get the latest tag, plus the number of (small) commits you did since that tag.
That means:

- you don't have to put a new tag if you don't want to
- but you still keep an *exact* reference the the version of your repo which was used for delivering your app.