# Add a Git alias containing a semicolon

Tags: git, parsing, git-config

When I try to create an alias

```
[alias]
    my-alias = submodule foreach 'git foo ; git bar'
```

Git (version 1.7.1) spews the error

```
user@host:/path/repo.git$ git my-alias
error: unclosed quote
fatal: Bad alias.my-alias string
```

It appears that `.gitconfig` uses weird parsing rules, so that `;` is treated as starting a line comment, even inside of a quote.

How do I specify this alias?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Wrap the entire alias command in double quotes:

```
my-alias = "submodule foreach 'git foo ; git bar'"
```

The double quotes cause the `.gitconfig` parser to pass the semicolon. The single quotes are still needed to delimit the argument to `submodule foreach`; without them, it gets parsed as

```
submodule foreach 'git foo'
git bar
```

so that `git bar` only gets executed once, at the end.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this is related to the semicolon, but here goes - here is another test for git alias, using `bash`:

```
[alias]
        testbash = "!bash -c \"ix=1; echo a\\$ix\""
```

test:

```
$ git testbash 
a1
```

Any other form of escape gives me either plain old "fatal: bad config file line", or “Unterminated quoted string” or “unexpected EOF” (see also [shell - Calling bash from sh (dash) with commands read from args, and "Unterminated quoted string"/"unexpected EOF" - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73219/calling-bash-from-sh-dash-with-commands-read-from-args-and-unterminated-quot/73220#73220))

Also for multiline:

```
[alias]
  testbashm1 = "!bash -c \"ix=1; echo a\\$ix; \
echo b\\$ix \""
  testbashm2 = "!bash -c 'ix=1; echo a$ix; \
echo b$ix '"
```

... and add `\n\` to the end of line, if you want to use inline `bash` comments (`#`):

```
[alias]
  testbashm3 = "!bash -c 'ix=1; echo a$ix; \n\
    #echo b$ix ; \n\
    echo \"c$ix\" ; '"
```

Answer (score 3):

For complete flexibility, define and call a function:

```
[alias]
    conf = ! "                                \
        f () {                                \
            git config \"$@\" --get-regexp .  \
            | sort;                           \
        };                                    \
        f"
```

This alias can be called as `git conf`, `git conf --local` or `git conf --global`, and the extra options are inserted in the appropriate place.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use doublequotes (`"`) rather than singlequotes (`'`).

```
[alias]
    foo = "submodule foreach 'echo foo; echo bar'"
    bar = submodule foreach 'echo foo; echo bar'
```

---

```
$ git foo
foo
bar
$ git bar
fatal: Bad alias.bar string: unclosed quote
```

Comment: That doesn't quite work; `echo bar` only gets executed once at the end.

Comment: Try using doublequotes to wrap the entire alias value instead.

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap the command into double-quotes, e.g.:

```
foo       = !"echo foo; echo bar"
```

To include semicolon for `find`, double-escape it, like:

```
pull-all  = !"find . -name .git -type d -print -execdir git pull origin \\;"
```

Same with your command:

```
my-alias  = "submodule foreach 'git foo; git bar'"
```

For troubleshooting, prefix your command with `GIT_TRACE=1` to debug your alias, e.g.

```
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git my-alias
18:16:07.904421 git.c:282               trace: alias expansion: my-alias => 'submodule' 'foreach' 'git foo; git bar'
18:16:07.904437 git.c:557               trace: exec: 'git-submodule' 'foreach' 'git foo; git bar'
18:16:07.904443 run-command.c:347       trace: run_command: 'git-submodule' 'foreach' 'git foo; git bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have

```
[alias]
  sm-clean-all = "submodule foreach --recursive 'git clean -fXd'"
```