# putting regex to make git diff split words at punctuation into .gitconfig file

Tags: regex, git, diff, git-diff, git-config

## current setup

My `.gitconfig` currently includes this alias:

```
[alias]
    wdiff = diff --color-words --histogram
```

to let me write `git wdiff` and get word-by-word rather than line-by-line `diff` output. I use this for writing scholarly prose in LaTeX.

## goal

This method divides words only at white space. I would like to divide at punctuation marks so that, for example, `last word of sentence.` changed to `last word of sentence.\footnote{New footnote.}` produces `diff` output that looks something like this:

> last word of sentence.**\footnote{New footnote.}**

rather than the current output:

> last word of *sentence.***sentence.\footnote{New footnote.}**

(where italics means *deletion* and bold means **addition**).

## attempted solution

I found [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36192897/how-do-i-split-words-on-punctuation-in-git-diff) that begins with a regex that does exactly what I want in the command line, but I haven't figured out how to put this in my `.gitconfig` file without producing the error message `fatal: bad config line 12 in file /Users/alex/.gitconfig`. This is what I put in my `.gitconfig` file:

```
[alias]
    wdiff = diff --color-words='[^][<>()\{},.;:?/|\\=+*&^%$#@!~`"'\''[:space:]]+|[][<>(){},.;:?/|\\=+*&^%$#@!~`"'\'']' --histogram
```

The problem seems to be the semicolon.

A [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478496/add-a-git-alias-containing-a-semicolon) that deals with a similar problem in `.gitconfig` suggested putting double-quotes around an entire alias. But when I do that in my case, I get the same error message. I think this is because the regex also includes double-quotes.

## question

How can I put the regex into my `.gitconfig` file such that it can be properly parsed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was confused as well until I found [this page of documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_syntax). The part you are interested in is:

> A line that defines a value can be continued to the next line by ending it with a `\`; the backslash and the end-of-line are stripped. Leading whitespaces after `name =`, the remainder of the line after the first comment character `#` or `;`, and trailing whitespaces of the line are discarded unless they are enclosed in double quotes. Internal whitespaces within the value are retained verbatim.
>
> Inside double quotes, double quote `"` and backslash `\` characters must be escaped: use `\"` for `"` and `\\` for `\`.
>
> The following escape sequences (beside `\"` and `\\`) are recognized: `\n` for newline character (NL), `\t` for horizontal tabulation (HT, TAB) and `\b` for backspace (BS). Other char escape sequences (including octal escape sequences) are invalid.

So, here the correct alias in `.git/config`:

```
wdiff = "diff --color-words='[^][<>()\\{},.;:?/|\\\\=+*&^%$#@!~`\"'\\''[:space:]]+|[][<>(){},.;:?/|\\\\=+*&^%$#@!~`\"'\\'']' --histogram"
```

In this case you just need to enclose everything in double quotes and escape both `"` and backslashes.