# GIT checking out code from output of "git describe"

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-describe

I am thinking about using `git describe` to generate automated version numbers. As suggest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120001/what-is-the-git-equivalent-for-revision-number).

My question is that if I get o/p of `git describe` as `v2.0-64-g835c907`,
how can I checkout that particular revision number using git in future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly this may be what you want:

```
git checkout `git describe`
```

Answer (score 7):

You can just do

```
git checkout v2.0-64-g835c907
```

The output from git describe can be used as a reference to a commit itself