# How to indicate build version in a DRY and automated manner across project & version control?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, git, version-control

I'd like to have a version indicated for my builders i.e Version:101, that is both in my project and in the comments of my version control (GIT).

This is to ensure that if I ever need to change code deployed in production I can find that codes version number from the project, and match it to the GIT revision, then check it out to modify and re-deploy.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC . does anyone know of a good way to do this? I'd like it DRY I.E I mark the version n.o in the code and then GIT picks it up or something.

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the git equivalent for revision number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120001/what-is-the-git-equivalent-for-revision-number)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you want that your binaries have the version number somewhere. I'm assuming you are using annotated tags for versioning. For a C++ project I did something like this:

Create a pre-build script that runs the command [`git describe`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-describe.html) (and append `--match "v[0-9]*"` if you use tags for other purposes too) and spits out a file that you can use in the project. For my project, this was "gitversion.h" that had the following:

```
#define VERSION "v1.2.3-5-g472ac4f"
```

This file should be in your `.gitignore` file, you don't want it to end up in the repository.

Then use that file in your build as usual.