# git revision number with wix

Tags: c#, git, wix

Can I obtain the hash of the last commit and Version Tag from Git for my wix installer easily?

Generally I just want to build my software without changing the versions in seperate files. I just want to do it with git.

Comment: You might want to refine what you mean: [git cannot have revision numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4120038/2226988).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I build a preprocessor extension with [wix](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixdev/extensions/extension_development_preprocessor.html).
I used lib2git to get the tag and the hash. I needed to short the hash to 4 digits and convert it to integer, because wix does only support integer AFAIK.
With the preprocessor I was able to give my installer script the variable.