# Raise version when commit

Tags: git, phpstorm, githooks, git-rev-list

I have a project in php with the use of GIT and there is a file called "version" with inside "1". I want that when i commit the number is incremented. I am using the git hook feature with this script:

`num=$(cat version)
num=$(expr 0$num + 1)
echo $num > version
git add -u version`

All work fine except that when i check on the ide (phpstorm), the file stay "blue" (not syncronized) so if i click commit i see the file "version" modified.

Comment: do you add 'version' in versionning git system ?

Comment: the problem is that i need a remote version... i upload my php project on the host and i want know on the remote host which version i am using... i'm trying to do an automatic system instead edit manually a file version.txt

Answer (score 1):

1. You **must** to *ignore* this file and don't have it in repo
2. You reinvented the wheel and gonna duplicate a) already existing inside Git b) *always and automatically* correct information

In short: **don't do it** at all, do not solve the problem in **so wrong way**

Answers in [How to get the git commit count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677436/how-to-get-the-git-commit-count) and [this answer in what is the git equivalent for revision number?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4120179/960558) and a lot of [questions about git describe](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22git%20describe%22) (variations of second attempt) will give you a lot of ideas and methods getting changeset-count on the fly in pre-build step.

While incremental counter in DAG is, from my POV, is bad and poor concept, `git rev-list --count <revision>` or `git rev-list --all --count` is the most correct method for getting changesets counter

Comment: 1) which file i have to ignore? i want the file version in repository or it is useless