# Java Implementation of Oracle's DBMS_UTILITY.GET_HASH_VALUE Function

Tags: java, oracle, hashcode

I need the actual algorithm used by Oracle's `DBMS_UTILITY.get_hash_value` function. I need to be able to generate this information without access to an Oracle database.

Comment: When you're talking about hashing functions, you need to specify for what purpose - e.g. is it for detecting duplicates, spreading data evenly, or is it for a cryptographic application?

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I don't really see the relevance of *why*...not to mention the fact that I think that, in this case, it would violate my NDA to disclose that fact. I'm being asked to develop a tool that needs to replicate Oracle's hash function...isn't that reason enough?

Comment: You don't need to violate your NDA, you just need to be more specific than just "I want a hash function algorithm". That's like saying "I want the sorting algorithm" assuming there's only one - i.e. not specifying whether you want an algorithm that sorts faster, uses less memory, or performs fewer exchanges.

Comment: I don't really think that's a fair representation of what I asked, though. I'm asking for a very specific algorithm - the DBMS_UTILITY.GET_HASH_VALUE algorithm. I know I'm not the only person who would be interested in this (see, https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1528240). I understand it's important to be clear in your questions, but I don't see where I failed to do that.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. What you're asking for is a duplication of the algorithm in Java so that you can avoid a database call. I'm guessing you have existing code that calls `DBMS_UTILITY.get_hash_value`, and you want to implement it in Java so that your code still works effectively the same. Unfortunately the Oracle documentation doesn't specify the algorithm used, so I'm not sure that you're going to get an answer except by someone who can somehow reverse engineer Oracle's implementation.

Comment: Voting to reopen based on clarified requirements.

Comment: The actual situation is that, I am told, I do not have access to an Oracle database, but that I need to be able get the mapping of String -> DBMS_UTILITY.GET_HASH_VALUE.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm not sure if there's going to be an answer, but if someone does know it, it'll be interesting.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle doesn't detail the implementation of the hash, and [Tom Kyte has indicated](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:95412348059) that the implementation can change release to release. If you are looking for a hash function you can use in Java and Oracle, you can do SHA1 (and other) hashes using `sys.dbms_crypto.hash` in oracle, and `MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1")` (for details see this question - [Java String to SHA1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895523/java-string-to-sha1)).

If you need to use the same algorithim as Oracle's GET_HASH_VALUE, perhaps contacting Oracle support may help...

Comment: it's a hash function, of course it's going to get collisions! (note -how likely this is depends on what hash size you choose)

Comment: Yeah, but no one has yet found two messages that give a collision on an SHA-1 hash. For purposes of identifying a unique record or differences between two records based on typical database data, SHA1 should suffice. There's always SHA-256.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475648/sha1-collision-demo-example

Comment: You said "people have found collisions often with it" as if that indicated an inherant fault in its implementation. I felt that was a bit unfair. Also, you are making the assumption that the OP needs a hash that identifies unique records/differences between two records - an assumption which, I believe, is unwarranted given the lack of detail in the question. Note, however, I'm not downvoting your answer.

Comment: I don't need DBMS_UTILITY.GET_HASH_VALUE because it is a good hash function, I need it because it is the *exact* hash function that I need. It's pretty simple.

Comment: @Dan Forbes, Per Tom Kyte, the implementation detail of that function is not available, and *may change* between versions of the Oracle database. http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:95412348059 `We change the hash algorithm from release to release (it has happened at least once in the past and could happen again).  You need to look at alternative ways.`

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Agreed. I did assume that the need for a hash was in related to the records - I updated my answer to be a more general reason not to use it.