# md5 collision how is it possible?

Tags: md5, digital-certificate, private-key, hash-collision

i don't understand how one can create a rough Certificate just by making a MD5 collision. Even if you were able to find another string whose hash matches the original how would you sign it ? You do not have access to the Certificate authority's private key ?

Comment: if the hash is the same then the signature is the same. There is no need to sign anything, just copy the original signature over.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224113/examples-of-hash-collisions for answers